# MySql view shows wrong information from the database in jpa query

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, javafx

I have a view from mysql mapped by hibernate in a java project, when I first map the entity and consult the information, it gives the information I have in my DB, but when I insert new data into the tables my view is refering to, it repeats the first row again and again(in the view, the information on the tables is ok), as if I was inserting the same information in the view. However, in my DB the insert is ok, the view works and shows the correct information, therefore the only problem is the mapped view. I would like to know, if there is some way to fix the view problem.

This is the view mapped as an Entity

```
@Entity
public class Vistapendientes {
    private int aluId;
    private String aluNom;
    private String herNom;
    private Date soliFechaSalida;
    private Date soliFechaDevuelve; 
...
```

This is the information I get from the view in my DB

`select * from vistapendientes;`

```
17380010    Oscar   Pinzas punta 1  2019-05-18  2019-05-22
17380009    Ivonne  Pinzas punta 2  2019-05-14  2019-05-26
17380010    Oscar   Martillo 1  2019-05-21  2019-05-23
```

The query I use in the program is:

`jpa-ql> select v from Vistapendientes v`

And this is the info I get from that query

```
17380010    Oscar   Pinzas punta 1  2019-05-18  2019-05-22
17380009    Ivonne  Pinzas punta 2  2019-05-14  2019-05-26
17380010    Oscar   Pinzas punta 1  2019-05-18  2019-05-22
```

As you can see, the first row repeats itself, instead of showing me the actual information in my DB.

Of course, I expect to get the same result I get from my DB in the JPA-QL query I do in the program.
Thanks for reading.

Comment: The problem is most likely the underlying data, which is not what you think.

Comment: I don't understand, the data is supose to come from my DB, and in my DB the data is correct, both in tables and view. @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: Show us the MySQL code you used to define the view.

Comment: Here's the code, this gives me correct data when I consult it:

`create or replace view vistaPendientes as
select s.alu_id, a.alu_nom, h.her_nom, 
s.soli_fecha_salida, s.soli_fecha_devuelve
from Solicitud s, herramientas_en_solicitud sh, Herramientas h, Alumnos a, Maestros m
where s.soli_id = sh.soli_id and h.her_id = sh.her_id and s.alu_id = a.alu_id and s.mae_id = m.mae_id;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I could solve this was building the view directly in the program, through hibernate's 'mappedBy' property.

Answer (score 0):

Try Native Query :

@Query(value = "select * from vistapendientes", nativeQuery = true)

Vistapendientes getCompanyDetails();

Comment: So I implemented it like this, when i run that query directly, it gives me the correct info

`@Entity
@NamedNativeQuery(name = "SelectAll", query = "select * from vistapendientes")`

But, when I try to call it:

`List list = EMHandler.getEntityManager().createNamedQuery("SelectAll", Vistapendientes.class).getResultList();`

it gives me:

`java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0`